# merging profile views in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website where users commonly go to x/y/z/userprofile=123456  and so my analytics data is being polluted with a lot of different profile views. I want to merge them all into one 'viewed profile' bit of data.

Does anyone have any idea exactly what I should be putting into filters to get the information I want?

I am completely new to GA so I am really unsure where to start

Comment: Filters->New->Custom->Search and Replace->Filter Field "Request Uri" -> Search String  x/y/z/userprofile=(.+) -> Replace String x/y/z/userprofile. (Plus this is off-topic since it's not about code.)

Comment: ah, great, that mostly seems to work.
There's a slight issue in the live data with different language versions all showing up as different pages but I think with the recorded data this problem won't apply. I guess I have to wait a day or two until I can check!